# Minimum of three numbers, getting wrong answer for some values

Tags: python

I have tried to find smallest of three numbers but for some values the answer is wrong like 10,30,4 for example and it shows smallest number to be 10.

```
 num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num3 = input("Enter a number: ")
num4 = input("Enter a number: ")
if (num1 < num3) and (num1 < num4):
    print(num1)
elif (num3 < num4) and (num3 < num1):
    print(num3)
else:
    print(num4)
```

Comment: You need to parse the input as numbers before comparing them.

Comment: Why do input them as `num1`, `num3` and `num4`?

Comment: Asking the real question here @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Cause the number two button is not working in my key borad :)

Comment: Thank you for the help @Carcigenicate, much appriciated.

Comment: @Maveric: of all reasons...

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing text. You need to convert the input to `int` objects before comparing.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if (num1 < num3) and (num1 < num4):
    print(num1)
elif (num3 < num4) and (num3 < num1):
    print(num3)
else:
    print(num4)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: `input()` returns a **string**, and **strings are compared lexicographically**. So you should **convert it into an integer**, you can do this with `int(..)`:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if (num1 < num3) and (num1 < num4):
    print(num1)
elif (num3 < num4) and (num3 < num1):
    print(num3)
else:
    print(num4)
```

But nevertheless this is *not* a good way to calculate the minimum. What will you do if you have to calculate the minimum of 50 integers? Construct a hug amount of checks? Computer scientist *Edsger W. Dijkstra* once said:

> "*Two or more? Use a `for`!*" - Edsger W. Dijkstra

So in case you have to do work multiple times, you better use a `for` loop to handle that. The skeleton of such code fragment looks like:

```
for i in range(3):
    # ...
    pass
```

The body of the `for` loop (here `...`) will be repeated three times. Now what work can we put into the `for` loop? Of course we can query the user for input. So we can write:

```
for i in range(3):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    # ...
```

but now we still have to calculate the minimum. A way to handle this is by using an *accumulator*: a variable that is maintained through iteration, and updated accordingly. Here an accumulator can be the *thus far* obtained minimum. Since initially we have no minimum, we can initialize it with `None`:

```
thus_far_minimum = None

for i in range(3):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    # ...
```

Now in case `thus_far_minimum` is `None`, we can assign the `number` we have queried from the user. Furthermore in case `thus_far_minimum` is no longer `None` (so it is initialized), but `number` is less than `thus_far_minimum`, we can alter `thus_far_minimum` such that it now has the minimum. For example:

```
thus_far_minimum = None

for i in range(3):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if thus_far_minimum is None or number < thus_far_minimum:
        thus_far_minimum = number

print(thus_far_minimum)
```

at the end we can print the `thus_far_minimum` since it is the minimum over all the numbers we have seen.

Answer (score 0):

With `input()`, you get `strings`, so convert the input values to integers.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Set a variable to `num1`, then reset it as you compare `num1` to `num3` and `num4`.

```
smallest = num1

if num3 < smallest:
        smallest = num3    
if num4 < smallest:
        smallest = num4
        if num3 < num4:
            smallest = num3

print(smallest)
```